# HP LeftHand VSA "Usable Space" less than "Raw Space"

Tags: lefthand, hp

I have a few LeftHand VSA nodes that are very poorly documented (read: not at all). They are running on VMWare ESXi and each VSA has an 820GB VMDK allocated as its storage disks.

The 820GB VMDK is showing up inside VSA as Raw Space, but the Usable Space is showing as 607.79GB:

[image]

Now, on a normal, physical P4000 node I expect the usable space to be reduced due to RAID overheads. However a VSA node does not have any RAID configuration.

There are two LUNs, and neither LUN has any snapshots.

Why is this usable space so low, and can it be reclaimed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trolling the [HP Support Forums](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-StoreVirtual-Storage-LeftHand/VSA-and-Disk-size/td-p/5310207), it would appear that this happens if the VMDK size is increased after the VSA is initially deployed.

VSA does not support changing of the VMDK size, so you effectively have to remove the VSA from the management group, delete its disk, re-add it, and then re-join it to the management group and re-initialise the LUNs.

Comment: Really, no way to expand?  That's awful.

Comment: @ShaneMadden not expand whilst keeping the node online anyway. VSA has a few limitations like that. Single vNIC, no online expansion, and it just makes a SPAN over multiple VMDKs. If you can work with these limitations it's OK. (Note: Physical LeftHand nodes do not have these limitations)